# Double cover of a conic

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ a curve of genus $2$. Consider the map associated to the divisor $2K$. We have $\ell(2K) = 3$ by Riemann-Roch, so the map is $f : X \to P^2$. Since $\deg(2K) = 4$ we have $\deg(f) \cdot \deg(Y) = 4$, where $Y = f(X)$. I want to show that $f$ is a double cover of a conic curve.

With Riemann-Hurwiz formula, if $\deg(f) = 1$ then $g(Y) = 3$ so we would have $ 2 = 4 + \sum_i e_i$ which is absurd. On the other hand, the formula said that it is possible to have a $4:1$ cover of a line with ramification points such that $\sum_i e_i = 10$ is possible. So I don't know how to prove that such case is not possible, can I have some hints ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Y = f(X)$ is a line inside the $\mathbb P^2$, then the three global sections of $2K$ that you used to construct the morphism $X \to \mathbb P^2$ would be linearly dependent. This is impossible, because those three global sections of $2K$ were originally *chosen* to be linearly independent.

Comment: Of course, thank you !!